# Pass on all exports from a module object

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've got the following js file:

```
// db.js
export default /* ... */;

export const tableName = /* ... */;
```

And the following mock for it (using jest):

```
const MockDb = jest.genMockFromModule('../db.js');

export default MockDb.default;
export const { tableName } = MockDb;
```

Now, if I add an export to my original `db.js` file, I have to also touch the mock accordingly. I'd rather have the mock file just automatically export all exports from the `MockDb` object (which is a module object generated by `jest` holding a `default` key and other named properties for each export).

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), the `export * from X` 
syntax only works, when `X` is a string referring to a module. Can I somehow `export * from <moduleObject>`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible in ES6 modules, if you can switch to commonJS on both you could use `module.exports = jest.genMockFromModule('../db.js');` but there are other disadvantages (tree shaking and code splitting for example).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I somehow `export * from <moduleObject>`?

No, you can't. The export names must be statically declared, they can't be determined at runtime from an object.

The correct approach would a module loader plugin which automatically calls Jest when you do something like `import … from '../db.js!jest';`.